How can i keep a SharePoint list person col and a text col in sync - one with DisplayNames, the other with corresponding User names?
SharePoint 365 list, called Project Tracker
Column 1, DisplayName - Person column, No Groups, allow multiples.
Column 2, UserID - Multi lines Text.
For each DisplayName, want corresponding UserName, in column 2.
Example raw UserName format = JSmith@domain.any.com
Want UserNames to display like - JSmith, J0J0x7ab, J0Doe
Any ideas? I am fine with UserID being a calculated column and formatting as needed, or using a Power Automate flow, but pretty new to both. Any Advice?
